# Programmatically detecting console (administrative) session on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008, terminal-services

My application is running as service under Windows Server 2008. I'm looking for a way to detect an active console session. This can either be the console or a RDP session started as administrative session ("mstsc /admin").

The console session is called "Console" but I'm lost with RDP sessions.
Under Windows 2003 it was easy because a console session was always running with id 0. This changed since Vista so I'm looking for another way to find out.

I've already checked the WTSxxx Win32 API but have not found what I'm looking for.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you trying to determine when someone has logged into the box?

Comment: This is not going to work.  Google "session 0 isolation" to find out more about the reason a service can no longer interact with other sessions since Vista/Server2008.

Comment: @John: Yes, I want to know when someone has logged into the box, but only when it's an administrative (console) session. I do not want to detected a standard RDP session.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks, I know about that, I don't want to interact with the user. I only want to detect the presence of the console session.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the id of the session that is currently attached to the physical console, the API is [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that was **exactly** what I was looking for (seems I overlooked that).

Comment: Was promising but does not work. I have a 2008R2 box with a physical monitor/keyboard but use RDP via "mstsc /admin" to start a console session. My active session id is now 2, whereas WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId returns 1 (which is the disconnect physical session).

Answer (score 0):

One option is have your service [`CanHandleSessionChangeEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canhandlesessionchangeevent.aspx) set to true then implement [`OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onsessionchange.aspx) Then if `ChangeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.ConsoleConnect` you have had someone connect to the console.

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    if(changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.ConsoleConnect)
    {
        //use changeDescription.SessionId to find if the logged in user 
        //  to that session is an administrator.
    }
}
```